# Laravel 4 testing controllers which call a model

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm having some trouble getting a test to work in Laravel 4. I'm using `.env` files to manage my DB settings the way it is described in [Laravel's Configuration manual - Protecting Sensitive Configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration)

**The** `app/config/database.php` **file looks like:**

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => $_ENV['dbhost'],
    'database'  => $_ENV['database'],
    'username'  => $_ENV['dbusername'],
    'password'  => $_ENV['dbpassword'],
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

**The controller method being tested:**

```
public function getTaxonomies()
{
    if (Input::has('page')) {
        $limit = (Input::get('limit')) ? Input::get('limit') : 15;

        $taxonomy = Taxonomy::with('photos')->paginate($limit)->toArray();

        return Response::json(array(
            'Taxonomies' => $taxonomy
        ));
    }

    return Response::json(array(
        'Taxonomies' => Taxonomy::all()->load('photos')->toArray()
    ));
}
```

**The test:**

```
<?php

# app/tests/controllers/TaxonomyControllerTest.php

class TaxonomyControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testGetTaxonomies()
    {
        $this->action('GET', 'TaxonomyController@getTaxonomies');

        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is `ErrorException: Undefined index: dbhost`. I realize this is because the `$_ENV` var is not being populated in CLI. So my question is, how am I supposed to handle db creds for testing?

Update:

So I added an empty `database.php` file to my `app/config/testing` folder and now I'm no longer getting that error. I'm assuming it's because the database isn't being called anymore? Should I just be using mockery to test with data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: You may create a file for each environment supported by your
>   application. For example, the development environment will load the
>   .env.development.php file if it exists.

Just create `.env.testing.php` file and write your test database credentials in it.

```
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Credentials
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'dbhost'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'database'   => 'database',
    'dbusername' => 'username',
    'dbpassword' => 'password',

);
```